# "gut Deutsch sprechen" or "Deutsch gut sprechen"?

Tags: adverb

I do know that

> I speak German well

means

> Ich spreche gut Deutsch

But is

> Ich spreche Deutsch gut

correct too? If not then why? And the most important: why do I have to put **gut** before **Deutsch** and not after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both is correct and it means the same with a slight difference in emphasis (yet can be used interchangably):

> Ich spreche gut Deutsch

This is the usual form used most often. You are talking about the German language and specify how well you speak it. You might continue with particularities on listening, reading, writing or special fields where your proficiency is better or worse.

> Ich spreche Deutsch gut

You talk about languages and specify how well you speak German (thus you emphasise that your *German* skill is good (as compared to others). You might continue to mention that your Italian proficiency is mediocre and your native tongue is Russian and that your brother's English equally good.

Comment: What type of speech is "gut" in each of the sentences?

Comment: It's an adverb in either case